# Realizar un recorte circular dentro de una imagen PNG usando JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3

Tags: javascript, html5, css3

¡Hola a todos!

Necesito lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado investigando y toda la información que he encontrado está basada en recortes de imágenes enfocado en los bordes. Por lo tanto, tecnologías como Jcrop no funcionarían en este caso.

Miré también la Composición y Recorte de este sitio: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Compositing

Pero no encontré algo parecido a lo que requiero.

Por ello, mi pregunta es la siguiente, ¿cómo puedo realizar esto utilizando JavaScript, CSS3 y/o HTML5?

Código que he intentado (utilizando la clase Texture de Phaser 3):

```
let originalTexture = this.textures.get("Estrella").getSourceImage();
let recorteCircular = this.textures.get("recorteCircular").getSourceImage();
let newTexture = this.textures.createCanvas("objetoNuevo", 
originalTexture.width, originalTexture.height);
let ctx = newTexture.context;
ctx.drawImage(originalTexture, 0, 0);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'xor';
ctx.drawImage(recorteCircular, 50,50);
let objetoNuevo = this.add.image(centroW-10, centroH-150, "objetoNuevo");
```

Saludos.

Comment: Por favor muestra aquello que hayas intentado en codigo, si bien ya haz investigado al respecto el sitio pide que tengas un codigo minimo y verificable del cual partir para nosotros dar solucion a tu pregunta.

Comment: He agregado un código que me ha funcionado, pero fue con la ayuda del Framework de videojuegos Phaser 3. Es el efecto que deseo, no obstante, me gustaría hacerlo recurriendo a tecnologías más puras con JavaScript/HTML5/CSS3.

Comment: Creas el canvas, pintas la imagen y encima de la imagen pintas un circulo en la pocision deseada, luego lo exportas como png y listo, todo esto se puede hacer nativamente sin frameworks, ahora bien, sobre como hacerlo... quiza en un rato explique la forma de hacerlo en codigo.

Comment: La exportación no la necesito realmente, ya que sólo necesito crear el recorte y utilizar la imagen resultante (recortada), en el mismo sitio. Vale, te lo agradecería que me lo explicarás en código.

Answer (score 1):

No tengo tu imagen, asi que supongamos que este simple rectangulo AZUL es tu imagen:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 200;

function draw(){

  //Save guarda las propiedades del canvas al momento y restore las restaura a como estaban
  //Es importante usarlas para no tener problemas con principalmente los colores o medidas
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.restore();
  
  //Aqui en vez de usar fillRect usarias drawImage
  ctx.save();
  ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
  ctx.fillRect(100, 50, 100, 100);
  ctx.restore();
  
  //Despues de que se pinte la imagen pintamos el circulo
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(150, 75, 20, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  
}

draw();
```

```html
<canvas id = "canvas"></canvas>
```

No te preocupes por la pregunta de si "Eso no es lo mismo, yo estoy usando una imagen".

Enrealidad da igual que estes o no usando una imagen, pues si la estas pintando en el canvas son simplemente pixeles.

Comment: El inconveniente de este método es que no recorta la imagen realmente. La idea es que si otra imagen se situase debajo del rectángulo, dicha imagen de abajo se debería ver a través del recorte circular.

Comment: Es decir, no la requiero para exportarla, sino para usarla en el mismo lienzo de trabajo. Correcto, necesito una nueva imagen recortada a partir de una original.

Comment: Hmmm... creo que ya entiendo el problema, pues...creo que lo mas facil en realidad es crear una copia de esa seccion de la imagen y pegarla encima en la parte exacta de la ultima forma